# Add www subdomain to my Wildcard Virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

On my local dev server, I set up test sites with the domain like this **projectName.dev**

Using the setting below in my Apache config file...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%1/www
   ServerAlias *.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows me to access `projectName.dev` in the browser and it will load the files from `E:/Server/htdocs/projects/projectName/www/`

I would like to modify this so that I can also access the same folders if I use the subdomain `www` so in my example `projectName.dev` and `www.projectName.dev` would load the same files.

Can someone help me to do this?  I don't understand the documentation very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%-2/www
   ServerName staging.dev
   ServerAlias *.dev www.*.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

You can use %-2 to always get the "project" name. %-2 give you the second part of the url from the end. For e.g., if url would be http://project1.dev/ then the docroot would be E:/Server/htdocs/projects/project1/www

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately this results in the same problem I kept running into...the `project.dev` will load the correct data and `www.project.dev` loads a default apache 404 page

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: 2-3 years of trying to get this to work for my Dev server...I have asked this exact question at least 2-3 times on Serverfault in that time and you are the first one to give me a working solution...THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

The ALex_hha reply is correct, the problem is the %1 in the VirtualDocumentRoot. that is replaced by the hostname used. using both multiple wildcard variants and VirtualDocumentRoot is always tricky.

You have 2 solutions:

1. replace the %1 my a hardcoded `projectName.dev`.
   If you have many projects you would need to create a virtualhost config for each project, but just for one is a good workaround.
2. create 2 configs:

   ```
   # www.project.dev format 
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%2+/www
     ServerName www.*.dev
   </VirtualHost>

   # project.dev format
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%1/www
     ServerName *.dev
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

the %2+ says that you want the second and forward part of the hostname received. Check the [mod_vhost help page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) for more info

You are not using a unix, but on unix you could also do a symbolic link from the www names to the project names:

```
cd /srv/
for i in *; do 
   # bypass if not a directory
   if [ ! -d "$i" ]; then continue; fi
   # bypass if already created
   if [ -e "www.$i" ]; then continue ; fi
   # bypass if already a www
   echo $i | fgrep -q "www" && continue
   ln -s $i www.$i
done
```

This way both the projectname and www.projectname point to the same place